# How can I compile a android project to a apk file without using any paid solution or any IDE or eclipse?

Tags: android, vb.net, eclipse

How can I compile a android project to a apk file without using any paid solution or any IDE or eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an android project in maven and compile it at the command line without using any IDE.  You need the Android SDK, of course.

Comment: Can it be done without the use of Maven? Can I just do it with Android SDK alone?

Comment: Well you probably need a text editor.. and you need either Ant or Gradle or Maven installed..

both gradle and maven can be run from the command line.  This link [http://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle-android/] has a tutorial on setting up an android project using gradle, the Android SDK and your favorite text editor.